# I can't update certain records with queries using PDO, PHP, SQL, HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, sql-update

***First of all, sorry for my ugly code (and English).*** I am new to PHP, I need it for my study, but I still can't figure this out. I made a script that allows an logged in admin *(my own webapp)* to update some projects. In this case the name of the project and the code of the project. It shows the project it self, but it won't update it. I also don't get an error message or something like that.. Is there something wrong. I did the same thing for editing users and it worked perfectly, anyone can point out the wrong piece of code and why it is not working?

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
if( isset($_GET['edit']) )
{
    $id = $_GET['edit'];

    echo "<script>$('.haalweg').hide();</script>";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM kosten WHERE kostencode='$id'";
    $consultants = $db->prepare($query);
    try {
        $consultants->execute(array());
        $consultants->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($consultants as $consultant){
            $naam = $consultant['omschrijving'];
            $email = $consultant['email'];
            $admin = $consultant['admin'];
            $ccode = $consultant['kostencode'];
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "<script>$('Er iets is misgegaan, wilt u opnieuw proberen alstublieft!');</script>";
    }

}

if( isset($_POST['update']) )
{
    $newName = $_POST['nieuwnaam'];
    $id      = $_POST['consultantcode'];
```

**This is the not working query, I don't get errors (eve though I did not make one).**

```
    $query="UPDATE kosten SET omschrijving='$newName', kostencode='$id' 
    WHERE consultantcode='$id'";

    $update = $db->prepare($query);

    $update->execute(array());
    $_SESSION['admin'] = $newAdmin;
    header("refresh:0.8;url=adminedit.php" );

}
?>


<br><br>
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="width: 40%; margin:0 auto;"> 
    <div class="panel-heading">Users editen</div>
    <div class="panel-body">


        <form action="editk123.php" method="POST" class="login-card">
            <p><input type="hidden" name="consultantcode" value="<?php echo $ccode;?>">
                <p>Naam:  <input type="text" style="margin-left:9.6%; width:30%; border-radius:5px; padding:2.5px;" name="nieuwnaam" value="<?php echo $naam;?>">
                                    <p>Code:  <input type="text" style="margin-left:9.6%; width:30%; border-radius:5px; padding:2.5px;" name="consultantcode" value="<?php echo $ccode;?>">
                                            <br><br><button class="btn btn-default" id="abdel"> <input type="submit" name="update" style="background: none;border: none;text-align: center;margin-left: -11px;" value="Invoeren">
                </button>
                <a href="adminpage.php">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="padding: 7px;width: 70px;">Terug</button>
                </a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM kosten";
$rows = $db->prepare($query);
try {
    $rows->execute(array());
    $rows->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($rows as $row){

    }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "<script>$('Er iets is misgegaan, wilt u opnieuw proberen alstublieft!');</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: If `WHERE consultantcode='$id'"` is your actual code, it's missing a semi-colon.

Comment: 'the name of the project and the code of the project'. I mean the project number ofcourse with projectcode.

Comment: Plus, this [`error_reporting(0);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) doesn't help the cause.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oops, I did not do that on purpose. Thanks for noticing it, I will change this immediately!

Comment: Is `session_start();` loaded? Since you are using sessions. You should also add `exit;` after `header("refresh:0.8;url=adminedit.php" );`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes my `session_start();` is loaded. Exit did not change anything, but the funny thing is.. This code is exactly the same for my user editing page and that worked..

Comment: Try and clear the sessions then, if you say it worked for the other. Could be something in (server) cache also. You should use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Already tried that. Didn't worked.

Comment: Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened in your DB connection file, see if it yields anything. Plus, I edited my above comment in regards to error reporting, since you should not be disabling it with `error_reporting(0);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I already have that in my DBcon file, but I got two errors as soon as I hit update button 
`<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: naam in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\mocroneger\editk123.php</b> on line <b>89</b><br />`

`<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: ccode in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\mocroneger\editk123.php</b> on line <b>90</b><br />`

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to figure how to fix this. However, you now know what to look for. If I come up with anything, I will let you know. One thing that perplexes me is `$id = $_GET['edit'];` and then you're doing `$id = $_POST['consultantcode'];` so that could be an issue, least for that one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- All right, thanks for trying to help me out. Appriciate it! ;)

Comment: Also, instead of doing `catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "<script>$('Er iets is misgegaan, wilt u opnieuw proberen alstublieft!');</script>";
}` you should use `catch(PDOException $e) { print $e->getMessage(); }` should there be something important. Also `var_dump();` on your variables to see what is going through or not, or `print_r();` using variables inside the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select the entry, you're assigning $ccode to be whatever is in column kostencode in the database (kostencode being the edit ID you passed in the URL, which you use to select the row).

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM kosten WHERE kostencode='$id'";
...
$ccode = $consultant['kostencode'];
```

You then embed this value in the form as consultantcode:

```
<p><input type="hidden" name="consultantcode" value="<?php echo $ccode;?>">
```

When the data is posted back, you assign this back to $id:

```
$id      = $_POST['consultantcode'];
```

And then you try to update the row where the column consultantcode equals that id:

```
$query="UPDATE kosten SET omschrijving='$newName', kostencode='$id' WHERE consultantcode='$id'";
```

But you never retrieved the value of consultantcode in the first place - you retrieved kostencode as the id to use. The value of consultantcode in the record you originally read is unknown (you never assign it to anything), and therefore you don't know it to update the record using that as the id. Based on the variable naming "ccode", it seems you actually want to work with consultantcode as the key, and probably should change the assignment of ccode as follows:

```
$ccode = $consultant['consultantcode'];
```

That change should get your record to update - you will need to decide for yourself if that's the correct fix, or if you meant to use the IDs the other way around.